# Errors when making tables with the flextable package

Tags: r, flextable

So before with reporters i made a matrix consisting purely of text and then made it into a flextable and at last added it to my Word document. That way i created a header for my document. Example:

```
Header <- matrix("",1,3)

Header[1] <- paste("bla bla") 
Header[2] <- paste("blu blu")  
Header[3] <- paste("ble ble")  

myheader <- FlexTable(data = Header,                                                                                   header.columns = F,
                      add.rownames = F,
                      header.cell.props = cellProperties( background.color = "white" ),
                      header.text.props = textProperties( color = "black",
                                                          font.size = 11),
                      body.text.props = textProperties( font.size = 11, 
                                                        font.weight = "bold"))
```

Now when i try to convert it into a flextable with the new function:

```
myheader <- flextable(Header)
```

It says

> " Error in flextable(Header) : is.data.frame(data) is not TRUE"

or by:

```
myheader <- flextable(Header, col.keys = names(Header))
```

It says

> " Error in flextable(Header, col.keys = names(Header)) : 
>     unused argument (col.keys = names(Header)"

What am i doing wrong?
Thank you in advance! 
Ps. Feel free to modify my visual presentation (im still trying to figure it out on here). 
Also i just noticed, that i get the same problem with data tables, so theres definitely something i've missed.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Header` object is a `matrix`:

```
class(Header)
[1] "matrix"
```

You can convert it to a `data.frame` using `as.data.frame()`

```
library(flextable)
flextable(as.data.frame(Header))
```

[image: flextable result]

Alternatively, you could use `tableHTML` which also accepts matrices:

```
library(tableHTML)
Header %>% 
  tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
            theme = "scientific")
```

The result here is:

[image: tableHTML result]

Comment: Thank you @clemens! It worked. Do you know how i can move this to the header part of my docx? Im using the same template i did before, or i think:                           `doc201 <- read_docx(path = "Style.docx") `                                                                 But it keeps ending up in the text part.

Comment: I think you may want to ask a separate question for that one, I can't answer it without more detail and especially not in the comments